# Video playback software/formats for a 386?

Tags: ms-dos, video, software, windows-3.x

Wanting to have my 386DX @ 20MHz play a video (any video), just as a demo. I'd prefer it to be watchable (eg 10fps and not a tiny 10x10 pixel) as opposed to a slideshow.

What player software could I use? I have MS-DOS/Win3.1 installed.

Would be interested in knowing the max/best video quality format and settings available for say 286, 386, 486! Then I could make my own videos.

EDIT: Ideally I'm after "real" video and not animation.

Comment: Probably it would be Autodesk Animator's .FLI/.FLC

Comment: How about animated GIF? The thing is, there are not much "video" formats, as even decoding a JPG file took a lot of time, and therefore the usual thing was not trying to do "video" but "animation". Formats and programs that are usable for video playback became much later, when CD-ROMs could contain enough space for content and CPUs were already beyond 386DX/20 MHz.

Comment: I also remember using fli,gif,mpg on 386. The best MS-DOS viewer I know of was `qv.exe` quick view (knows also Divx and sound but not sure if it runs on 386 as I used it later...) on 386 there was QPV for images (GIF included not sure if also mpg) and cant remember the old mpg and fli viewer names (it wasnt QV nor PV) however IIRC it was only 256 color and low resolutions without sound and only for small videos... it took ages to decompress mp3 to wav on 386 DX40 (like 30min for song)... IIRC games used bik format but not sure if also on386 or latter on

Comment: @Spektre While a 386 can't play an MP3 realtime, it sure can't take 30 mins to decompress it, because a 100 MHz 486 can play realtime. Encoding a song to MP3 on a 100 MHz 486 did take about 30 minutes.

Comment: I stand corrected, it must have been a FLI viewer

Comment: @Justme The MS-DOS SW I got at that time was really that slow on x386 ... btw that *.mpg where well around 200x200 resolution or less and maybe 8fps ... IIRC I used ISA Trident 9000C then...

Comment: @Spektre For real mpeg video you'd want some PCI S3 Trio with YUV overlay support, not ISA Trident.

Comment: @Justme: Not all MP3 decoders are created equal, some are better optimized than others.  But also, some use floating point, so could be extremely slow if emulating x87 instructions by trapping on a machine without a hardware FPU.  Unlike 486DX, [386DX doesn't imply hardware FPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I386#Chip_variants), so it's easy to imagine a factor of 10 or more in performance not only to trap but to do software FP to emulate 80-bit x87.  (30 mins to decode a 3 min song.)  Some MP3 decoders use fixed-point integer and wouldn't have this problem, but Spektre didn't say...

Comment: (video encode/decode doesn't normally use floating point even today; the 2D DCT transform is normally done using integer operations, so the lack of an x87 FPU in a 386 isn't a major problem for video decode, just overall low speed and lack of SIMD such as MMX for modern video formats.)

Comment: @Vlad IIRC my trident had ~4.5MByte/s direct VRAM access write speed resulting in theoretical ~13 fps on 320x200 but those videos back then where even smaller so VGA speed was not a problem ... btw. I never liked S3 some friends did have them ad they where usually paint in the a...

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes your assumptions sound right I did not have 387 FPU at that time so MP3 decoding DCT was slow... IIRC mpg Video at that time used usually hardcoded 8x8 DCT on integers +/- 4cc encoding which my AMD 386 was relatively good at

Comment: @Spektre S3 had YUV overlays, which did not exist on ISA video cards. This feature allows to skip the final step of YUV-RGB color space transformation. The conversion alone would kill the performance on 386, regardless of the video card throughput.

Comment: @Vlad never coded mpg decoder but I think simple XLAT would be enough for that conversion so no big deal of performance if coded right

Comment: @Spektre XLAT from 24-bit of YUV pixel? jpeg/mpeg are not using indexed color, it's a continuous space, just like true color RGB. The whole XLAT will not fit in memory sizes typically associated with 386 PCs.

Comment: @Vlad I do not think those old MPG where 24bit ... and even if where you can simply downgrate to 16 or less bits and tables for that fit into 386 memory easily (even single segment) something similar like I did in here [Effective gif/image color quantization?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30265253/2521214) this is not single XLAT anymore but still fast and if you realize you can use 256 color mode VGA palette you have even few more operations per pixel less

Comment: In theory you could hide a mini-pc(e.g. rpi) in the case and let the video card bit-blit it to the monitor.

Answer (score 20):

On a 20MHz 386 (or really, any 386), the main animation format was [Autodesk Animator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Animator) (`.fli` or `.flc` files). A number of players are available, *e.g.* [FLIC!](https://www.sac.sk/download/graph/flic102.zip) (which was written specifically to be usable on a 20MHz 386) or Autodesk’s own [AAPlay](https://archive.org/details/AAPlay_1020) (this is the Windows version; there was a DOS player too).

You shouldn’t expect anything better than 320×200 in 256 colours on a 386; while SVGA cards common in (later) 386 computers support higher resolutions and colour depths, the CPU is just too slow for anything more. You can see [examples of FLIC animations](http://low.fi/%7Evisy/fli/) to get an idea of what to expect.

Quite a few games also used Animator for their animated sequences, *e.g.* Microprose’s Formula One Grand Prix. Some games store these sequences as separate files, so they can be played back using any Animator player.

Animator Pro, the software used to create Animator animations, was released as open source software a few years ago; [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/AnimatorPro/Animator-Pro) is still available, but the download page is gone, as is the project web site.

Video (with audio) really became viable with 486 computers; some video-heavy games (notably, [Myst](https://www.mobygames.com/game/win3x/myst) and [The 7th Guest](https://www.mobygames.com/game/dos/7th-guest)) claim to work on 386s, but playing them on a 386 isn’t a fun experience in practice. Video formats used in games include [QuickTime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime) (Myst), [Indeo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeo) (Civilization II), and [Smacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smacker_video) (WarCraft II). In most cases, even if the game supported resolutions such as 640×480, the videos were played at lower resolutions (either using only part of the screen for video, or with a video mode switch). The first Indeo codec was specifically designed to provide adequate decoding performance on a 386 but I don’t know off-hand of a 386-playable game using it.

Comment: Myst was designed so that scenes would contain video within them, while the surrounding area was static.  This was sometimes subtle (e.g. an outdoor scene with a turning windmill on an otherwise-static background) and sometimes not (e.g. each elevator's door will be opaque except for a rather small window, and moving the elevator will only involve animating the part of the scene visible through the window).

Comment: Not sure OP is so interested in animation software for "boardroom" creatives. I read the question to be about video codecs that might work on a '386. Anyway, Deluxe Paint and the Animation add-on for MS-DOS seemed to be much more popular among game developers.

Comment: @BrianH Autodesk Animator was quite popular even with non-“boardroom” creatives. When I had my 386 I had loads of `.fli` files downloaded from BBSes. And I read the question somewhat literally, “Wanting to have my 386DX @ 20MHz play a video (any video), just as a demo.” — `FLIC` does the trick (albeit with no sound). I realise the OP may be after actual video codecs, but on 386s people watched animations, not videos.

Comment: Thanks, these animations work well and look impressive, and I found a demo player with files here: https://archive.org/details/3d_flics_2

Was really hoping for actual video though, if that's at all possible.

Answer (score 6):

Are hardware-accelerated videos allowed for the purposes of this question?

MPEG-1 decoding ISA cards exist, and as far as I can tell they are meant to work on a 386 running DOS. The "Xing MPEG Player" has a Windows 3.1 version that I have to imagine is intended to be used with one.   https://archive.org/details/xingmpegplayer

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a decoder board but this will help others!

Comment: I know there are posts here to the contrary, but I never saw anything below a 486 playing an MPG, and then, the 486 would require a hardware decoder.  I have a Panasonic CF-41 notebook (486) that took a hardware decoder pack when the floppy drive was removed, and a few full size ISA PC Motion cards (I think from Optibase?) - anyway, I would venture to say MPEG on a 386 was extraordinarily uncommon.  But then, I'm going from personal experience, so YMMV.

Answer (score 5):

There were MPEG-1 software encoders (e.g. CMPEG) & decoders/players (DMPEG, VMPEG) for MS-DOS that would run on a 386.

Bear in mind that frame sizes were tiny (e.g. 160x120), the display might have to be palettised for a 256-colour VGA display, and just because it *runs* on a 386 doesn't mean the frame-rate is anywhere near real-time! And the downloable MPEGs of the time were often video channel only.

I think mirrors of the SIMTEL archive still exist, so just go look.

Update 1: A quick search turned up an ancient [FAQ](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/FAQ/multimedua/mpeg-faq/part5.html) describing VMPEG 1.2 for DOS as "*high speed: e.g. 21 frames/s on a 386DX/33 for a 160x120 I frame sequence*" so that would be your broad target.

I'm pretty sure Win3.11 already had Media Player, so again you should be able to view .avi on a 386 that way.

Basically, the trick is to downscale the video until your machine can manage it...

Update 2 (based on the comments): The issue with the .avi route is that it opens the can of worms that is codecs and compatibility. I had a rummage in some old backups and found my old Win 3.11 SYSTEM.INI, excerpt is:

```
[mci]
WaveAudio=mciwave.drv 7
Sequencer=mciseq.drv
Mixer=mcimixer.drv
AVIVideo=mciavi.drv
MpegVideo=mcivmpeg.drv
QTWVideo=C:\WIN311\SYSTEM\MCIQTW.DRV
Animation1=mciaap.drv
CDAudio=mcicda.drv 1

[drivers]
midimapper=midimap.drv
Wave=mvproaud.drv
MIDI=opl3.drv
Mixer=mvmixer.drv
VIDC.MSVC=msvidc.drv
VIDC.RT21=indeo.drv
VIDC.CVID=iccvid.drv
VIDC.IV32=ir32.dll
VIDC.IV31=IR32.dll
VIDC.MRLE=MSRLE.drv
VIDC.YVU9=ir21_r.dll
WaveMapper=msacm.drv
MSACM.msadpcm=msadpcm.acm
MSACM.imaadpcm=imaadpcm.acm
```

My system had collected a few extra toys over the years, but you can see there's an AVIVideo driver defined and a list of codecs - VIDC.*. In the meantime, @DmytroL had a look on his laptop and (in a comment) reported:

> I happened to have a codec management tool from K-Lite codec pack installed on my Windows 10 laptop ... The Microsoft Video 1 and Microsoft RLE ones are also present and enabled...

So, it should be possible to check SYSTEM.INI to confirm that the Microsoft Video 1 and Microsoft RLE codecs are installed in Win 3.x, and then create a suitable video on a current Windows laptop.

The difficulty will be that the OP has very slow hardware and so will need to keep both frame rate and size right down: even 160x120@10fps looks way too optimistic. I can't comment on which codec would be a better choice - try both and see. In particular, such an old machine is likely to have a very primitive graphics card - there will also be the overhead of quantising the output display down to a palette of 256 or even just 16 colors (for a stock VGA card).

But it does indeed look as though one can still create a video on Win 10 today that will be viewable on a stock Win3.11 system.

Comment: Thanks, FYI there's an ISO of SIMTEL MS-DOS archive here: https://archive.org/details/Simtel20_Sept92

Comment: @KERR you can find more Simtel archives on http://cd.textfiles.com/. I had my DOS hat on too firmly, Windows 3.11 with its Media Player is a good idea!

Comment: @Stephen Kitt The trouble with .avi is that it opens the whole can of worms of differing codecs. E.g. the Indeo mentioned above had to be got separately, from Intel. One might think that a modern ffmpeg or VLC would be able to create a suitably primitive video file viewable with the original Video for Windows codecs but I've not checked (they were proprietary, after all).
Going through Windows will also naturally be slower; OP might want to start with 96x72 and work up, for a machine that old.

Comment: @LouKnee indeed. I’ve been looking into converting current videos to .fli/.flc, which isn’t straightforward either, but at least it wouldn’t involve finding an old Indeo codec...

Comment: @Stephen Kitt Though to be fair Microsoft have always been quite good on backwards compatibility, so it may well be that the old V4W codecs are still buried in the Accessories applets in modern Windows (I don't know, never used them myself).

Comment: @LouKnee I happened to have a codec management tool from K-Lite codec pack installed on my Windows 10 laptop, so here's what I got when querying VFW codecs: https://pasteboard.co/o3jx7GwUKb5B.png . 

Looks like the Indeo codecs are still there but possibly disabled. The Microsoft Video 1 and Microsoft RLE ones are also present and enabled (not visible on the screenshot but I hope you trust my word for it).

Comment: @DmytroL thanks for that, though it will be the OP rather than me that would play with it. But it does look like one should still be able to create a video on Win 10 today that will be viewable on a stock Win3.11 system.

(I will try to update my answer with some of these comments at some point).

Answer (score 3):

RAD Game Tools "Smacker" supports the 386 as the oldest supported hardware for playback.  Glorious 256 color video.  It dates from 1994 and was used by games in the mid 90's.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't care about historical usage, the best performing video playback format is called "8088 Corruption".

See:   http://www.oldskool.org/pc/8088_Corruption/

Answer (score 0):

Software suggestions - courtesy of @spektre :

**QuickView Pro for DOS**

> QuickView Pro is a 32 bit protected mode program and therefore needs
> at least a 80386 processor and a VGA card. It will run under DOS 3.0
> or better, or in a DOS shell under Windows 95/98/ME and OS/2. Most ISA
> sound cards are supported as well as some PCI sound cards.

- Video Playback: MP4, DivX, AVI, MPEG, MOV, FLC, DL, VideoCD and more
- Audio Playback: MP3, WAV, VOC and more
- Picture Display: JPG, BMP,GIF, PCX, TGA and more

http://www.multimediaware.com/qv/download.htm

---

**QuickView 1.03b**

> Note that the development of this DOS real mode version of QuickView
> is discontinued. However, the software is still of interest for use
> with old 286 systems, under low memory conditions or if you use
> QuickView with your own real mode programs.

http://www.multimediaware.com/qv/dnreal.htm